# How to mimic file uploads using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

PHP received a post request to upload a file.  `print_r($_FILES);` outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [resource] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.log
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php2O7WQy
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 6136
        )
)
```

Using PHP, I echo'd the various request data to the page as strings.

I also added the following JavaScript to the page:

```
var uri = document.getElementById("uri").textContent;
var body = document.getElementById("body").textContent;
var files = document.getElementById("files").textContent;
var headers = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("headers").textContent);
var contentType = document.getElementById("contentType").textContent;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open(method, uri);
for (var name in headers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < headers[name].length; i++) {
        console.log(name, headers[name][i]);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader(name, headers[name][i]);
    }
}
if(contentType) xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
var parsedFiles=JSON.parse(files);
if(typeof parsedFiles.resource !=='undefined') {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(parsedFiles)); //{"resource":{"name":"test.log","type":"application/octet-stream","tmp_name":"/tmp/php2O7WQy","error":0,"size":6136}}
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('resource', parsedFiles.resource.tmp_name, parsedFiles.resource.name);
    xhttp.send(formData);
}
else {
    xhttp.send(body);
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
```

However, when the server received the XMLHttpRequest, `$_FILES` is empty.

If I know the files tmp_name, how can I generate a XMLHttpRequest so the server uses that file?  As an alternative, should I be saving the file as a blob string on the page and sending that?

Comment: Just search here on SO. You're not the first that wants to submit a file with `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to upload a file using XHR try the below code.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "path/to/your/file");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "url");
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: wondering why you didn't go for the more modern approach of using xhr.onload = function() and went with the event listener means of doing so?

Comment: I am just using what worked for me, I haven't tried xhr.onload thanks for that I will definitely try that.

Comment: i'll post the alternative to your code in my answer with that little tweak in it, just so the person that asked the question has both alternatives.

Comment: Sure, that would be great for me too.

Comment: Thanks Sahil,  I think I was really close.  As seen by my original post, I tried `formData.append('resource', parsedFiles.resource.tmp_name, parsedFiles.resource.name);`.  Looks like I misread https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append and incorrectly swapped the 2nd and 3rd argument.

Comment: It happens, good to know it helped.
btw @syedmh is posting different approach feel free to try both.

Comment: @syedmh can't comment on your answer reputation problem the code looks nice and clean.

Comment: Still nothing.  Just saw `_test.php:58 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.`.  I see both of you used `fileInput.files[0]`.  That must be the actual file, and not the common file name.  Looks like I will need to save the file as a string on the client.  Think I am on the right track. 
 Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please try my updated answer. I believe that the adjustment I've made should do the trick.

Comment: `fileInput` is not defined, and thus nor is `fileInput.files[0]`.  Which part was changed?  Thank you

Comment: my answer is the other one

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to Sahil Paudel's answer, here's a slightly different way of writing that code to use more modern standards:

Lets take this as an example form:

```
<form>
    <input type='file'>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In order to submit this file, you can use the following:

```
document.querySelector(form button[type="submit"]).addEventListener('click', e => {
    
    e.preventDefault();

    let form, data, xhr;
    form = this.parentElement;
    data = new FormData(form);
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhr.open('POST', /*url*/);

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(this.status === 200) {
            // do something with a positive response
        }
    }

    xhr.onerror = function() {
        // handle errors
    }

    xhr.send(data);

});
```

This is a method I've used to upload files, and it automatically appends your files to your XMLHttpRequest and makes it available to you in `$_FILES` in PHP.